# Complexity of Dijkstra's Algorithm for Heap Implementation

Tags: algorithm, graph

In CRLS' book, the analysis of Dijkstra's algorithm is as follows:

How many times do you need to use the heap? One time for pulling off each node from the heap (i.e. Extract-Min in CRLS's book) --- O(N); and also every time when looking at the edge ---- O(E), you might need to change the distance (i.e., Decrease-Key in CRLS' book), which means to fix the heap order. And each heap operation needs O(logN) work.

***Thus, total time complexity: O((N + E)logN), which is O(ElogN) if all vertices are reachable from the source.***

My Question is:
Why the complexity becomes O(ElogN) if all vertices are reachable from the source? Why can we ignore the O(NlogN) part from O((N + E)logN)?

Comment: `O(E) * O(log N) = O(E log N)`

Comment: @Lrrr Thanks for your comment. Where does the O(NlogN) part in O((N+E)logN) go?

Comment: Anybody knows? Please help!

Comment: O(N log N) is less than O(E log N) because E is between O(N) and O(N^2) so we could ignore O(N log N)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all vertices are reachable from the source, then there are at least `N-1` edges in graph, therefore `E >= N-1`, `N = O(E)` and `O((N + E) log N) = O((E + E) log N) = O(E log N)`

Answer (score 2):

If all nodes are connected there must be at least N-1 edges. So E >= N-1 and thus N <= E+1 and N+E <= 2E+1 which is in O(E).

Comment: Smart! Thank you so much. Both of you give the same answer. I want to accept yours as well, if allowed.